# You might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process

Tags: bash, opencv, path, anaconda, virtual-environment

I am trying to run python code in virtual environment of conda. The thing is I have installed opencv using brew and using python from anaconda environment. There is library called qt which is in both (brew and conda). Now when I try to run my code it says you are loading two sets of qt binaries in the same process. I understood the error but I don't know how to disable qt binary either from conda or from brew.

After deleting the one from conda it works fine but some dependencies also gets deleted. Don't want that. Can somebody suggest me some way.

Answer (score 7):

If OpenCV's gui functionality is not required, then this is an option to avoid qt conflict.

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip install opencv-python-headless
```